# Metaprogram to determine if a class is output stream-able unexpected output

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I thought I had figured out how to make a template which determines if a class/struct is stream-able to an ostream (e.g., "print-able") but there is a flaw in the template I wrote to do this.  Looking to learn where I went wrong as well as any solutions to get the template to work the way I expect/want.

### So my questions are

1. Am I missing something pretty basic here or is this more complicated than the template takes into account?
2. I have not looked at the template's interaction with rvalue references: will they be problematic for the template as well?

Full code [here](http://ideone.com/elaFo5).

---

Here is the template

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class isOutputStreamable {
  private:
    template<typename V, typename W> static decltype(operator<<(std::declval<V>(), std::declval<W>()), std::true_type()) check_(int);
    template<typename, typename> static std::false_type check_(...);
  public:
    static const bool value = decltype(check_<T, U>(0))::value;
};
```

---

The classes I am testing

```
struct Empty {
};

struct Streamer {
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostream, const Streamer&) {
  return ostream << "Streamer";
}
```

---

The static_asserts that work the way I expect

```
// Streamer should show as ostreamable
static_assert( isOutputStreamable< std::ostream&, const Streamer& >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( isOutputStreamable< std::ostream&, const Streamer  >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( isOutputStreamable< std::ostream&,       Streamer& >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( isOutputStreamable< std::ostream&,       Streamer  >::value, "Goodness" );

// isOutputStreamable works with a value ostream for Streamer
static_assert( isOutputStreamable< std::ostream, const Streamer& >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( isOutputStreamable< std::ostream, const Streamer  >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( isOutputStreamable< std::ostream,       Streamer& >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( isOutputStreamable< std::ostream,       Streamer  >::value, "Goodness" );

// Empty should not show as ostreamable
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< std::ostream&, const Empty& >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< std::ostream&, const Empty  >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< std::ostream&,       Empty& >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< std::ostream&,       Empty  >::value, "Goodness" );

// With a const ostream nothing should show as ostreamable
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream&, const Streamer& >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream&, const Streamer  >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream&,       Streamer& >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream&,       Streamer  >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream , const Streamer& >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream , const Streamer  >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream ,       Streamer& >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream ,       Streamer  >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream&, const Empty&    >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream&, const Empty     >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream&,       Empty&    >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream&,       Empty     >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream , const Empty&    >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream , const Empty     >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream ,       Empty&    >::value, "Goodness" );
static_assert( !isOutputStreamable< const std::ostream ,       Empty     >::value, "Goodness" );
```

---

and then the static_asserts that do not

```
// Unexpected results: I wanted these to all fail
static_assert( isOutputStreamable< std::ostream, const Empty& >::value, "Badness" );
static_assert( isOutputStreamable< std::ostream, const Empty  >::value, "Badness" );
static_assert( isOutputStreamable< std::ostream,       Empty& >::value, "Badness" );
static_assert( isOutputStreamable< std::ostream,       Empty  >::value, "Badness" );
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

## Update

@Casey: Thanks for the help.  I was so convinced that there was something wrong with the template I guess I completely missed the fact that it might actually be matching correctly.  As for your suggestion about how to switch the template around this is certainly something that is easily do-able; however, I'm curious if there is not another solution that'll fit given what I'll say next.

The template is actually generated from what I had hoped would be a general macro to create these types of checker templates

```
   #define BINARY_FUNCTION_EXISTS_(FUNCTION_NAME_, CHECK_NAME_) \
    template<typename T, typename U> class CHECK_NAME_ {\
      private:\
        template<typename V, typename W> static decltype(FUNCTION_NAME_(std::declval<V>(), std::declval<W>()), std::true_type()) check_(int);\
        template<typename, typename> static std::false_type check_(...);\
      public:\
        static const bool value = decltype(check_<T, U>(0))::value;\
    };
```

Is it the case that this ostream-able template needs to be a special case because of the (undesirable in my case) matching template?  I think the answer is yes but I've already been confused once on this and it does not hurt to ask.  Thanks again.

Comment: adding an ampersand [fixes this](http://ideone.com/jFLcOy) but it may not be the correct solution

Comment: I think I would simply drop the first template parameter altogether and only check for `decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>())`.

Comment: Yes, I agree that you will have to special-case your macro. There seems to be no reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The standard library defines an unconstrained template function that provides rvalue stream insertion for all types in terms of lvalue stream insertion:

> ### C++11 §27.7.3.9 Rvalue stream insertion [ostream.rvalue]
>
> ```
> template <class charT, class traits, class T>
> basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
> operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>&& os, const T& x);
> ```
>
> <sup>1</sup> *Effects:* `os << x`
>
> <sup>2</sup> *Returns:* `os`

This is obviously breaking your detection for rvalue ostreams.

2. Since `decltype(std::declval<T>())` and `decltype(std::declval<T&&>())` are both `T&&`, it will work just fine with rvalue references; `IsOutputStreamable<T, U&&>::value` will be equal to `IsOutputStreamable<T, U>::value`.

Comment: @user3125280 Of course, it's #3 at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2 - who wouldn't think to look there?!?

Comment: I guess the obvious question is why that template doesn't fail, assuming it does call `os << x` (it must do no compile time checking, and wait till link time, which is fair enough) - and i know! right at the top of bookmark list, and i didn't even see it.

Comment: It's the nasty "unconstrained" part that I dislike. Seems it ought to be "forbidden from participating in overload resolution" when `std::declval<basic_ostream<charT, traits>&>() << std::declval<T const&>()` is not well-formed.